# Probability distribution of a bounded variable

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

I have a set of $n$ quantities $\lbrace X_1, \dots , X_n\rbrace$, initially all equal to $0$.
I have a set of $n$ stopping values $\lbrace M_1, \dots , M_n\rbrace$, with $M_j>0$ for each $j$.
I perform an experiment with each step having $k$ possible outcomes which probabilities are $\lbrace P_1, \dots , P_k\rbrace$.
Any outcome $z$ will increase the value of at least one $X_j$ quantity:
$\begin{cases}
X_1\gets X_1 + Q_{1,z}\\
\vdots\\
X_n\gets X_n + Q_{n,z}\\
\end{cases}$ with $Q_{j,z}\geq0$ for each $j$ and $z$, and $\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}Q_{j,z}>0$ for each $z$.
Steps are performed until at least one $X_j$ quantity reaches or exceeds its corresponding stopping value: $X_1\geq M_1\ or\ \dots\ or\ X_n\geq M_n$.
I am looking for the probability distribution of one quantity, say $X_j$, over the set $\left[0,M_j-1+\max\left(Q_{j,1},Q_{j,2},\dots,Q_{j,k}\right)\right]$.

For now, I solve this problem by using Markov chains with absorbing states.
However it involves solving systems of linear equations.
Thus my question is:
Is there a better (simpler, faster, more straightforward, ...) way to solve that problem, for instance a built-in formula using multinomial coefficients?
Thanks in advance for your answers.